# NodeJs routing-controllers: How can I Had dynamic parameter in middleware call

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, routes, routing-controllers

I have followed the tutorial from:

- https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#creating-your-own-express-middleware

But I do not find a way to inject dynamic parameters in @UseBefore/@UseAfter middleware call
Like this:

```
@Get("/something/:id")
@UseBefore(checkPermission(['canReadThis','canWriteThis']))
getOne(@Param("id") id: number) {
    // ...
}
```

Can someone gide me doing this?

I found this :

- https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers/issues/338#issuecomment-348169164

But I dont know how to handle data from the Context "Class" and "{req, resp, next}" like this

```
function loggingMiddleware(request: any, response: any, next?: (err?: any) => any): any {
  console.log('do something...');
  next();
}
```

Comment: why don't you receive your dynamic data over post, instead of dynamic route path

Comment: permission checking have to be private (I think), I d'ont want to create a spesific checker for each permission (for exemple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly Find out

My middlerware:

```
@UseBefore((request: any, response: any, next: Function) =>
  PermissionsChecker(request, response, next)({
    permissions: ['ONE_PERMISSION', 'ANOTHER_ONE']
  })
)
```

My Handler Function

```
export const PermissionsChecker = (request: any, response: any, next: Function) => 
  async ({ permissions }: { permissions: string[] }): Promise<any> => { 
     // ... do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function executeMiddlewareList (middlewareList, req, res, next) {
   async.eachSeries(middlewareList, function(middleware,callback) {
      middleware.bind(null,req,res,callback)()
   }, function(err) {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json({error: err});
      next();
   })
}
```